# SwiftUI: Let VoiceOver wait onAppear

Tags: swiftui, avaudiosession, voiceover

I have a SwiftUI view that plays a short audio clip as soon as it appears, in `onAppear`.
VoiceOver also starts reading the screen contents when the view appears.

How do I ensure VoiceOver doesn't interrupt my audio clip?

My view looks like this:

```swift
// Super simple view with an image and a button.
FirstTimeLandingView(continueAction: {
    [...]
})
.onAppear {
    AudioManager.shared.playWelcomeMessage()
}
```

And the audio is played using an `AVQueuePlayer`.

```swift
class AudioManager {
    static var shared = AudioManager()
    
    private let audioPlayer = AVQueuePlayer()

    init() {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
          do {
              try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
              try audioSession.setActive(true)
          } catch {
              debugPrint(error)
          }
    }

    func playWelcomeMessage() {
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: Audio.welcome.fileURL!)
        audioPlayer.insert(playerItem, after: nil)
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

I have tried setting `.startsMediaSession` and `.playsSound` as an accessibility trait like this, but it doesn't work:

```swift
FirstTimeLandingView(continueAction: {
  [...]
})
.onAppear {
    AudioManager.shared.playWelcomeMessage()
}
.accessibilityAddTraits(.startsMediaSession)
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: you can try exploring `AccessibilityFocusState ` and `UIAccessibility.Notification` for the same above. A content that is rapidly changing like a timer, slider etc you can use notifications for their progress. and with Focus State you can hold the voiceover focus on your UI till the audio is not finished and you post some notification for it.